# Derivative of Dot Product as matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-analysis, inner-products, matrix-calculus

I've come across this definition when looking into how to differentiate parameter vectors in statistics.

Given $ \pmb{x}^{T} \pmb{x}$ 
$$\frac{\partial (\pmb{x}^{T} \pmb{x}) }{\partial \pmb{x}}=2\ \pmb{x}^{T}$$

And the proofs I've seen utilize the product rule while holding $\pmb{x}^{T}$ and $\pmb{x}$ constant. (Source: http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~csip/tirgul3_derivatives.pdf)

$$\frac{\partial (\pmb{x}^{T} \pmb{x}) }{\partial \pmb{x}}=  \frac{\partial ({x}^{T} \pmb{x}) }{\partial \pmb{x}} + \frac{\partial (\pmb{x}^{T} x) }{\partial \pmb{x}}= \pmb{x}^{T} + \pmb{x}^{T} = 2\pmb{x}^{T} $$

I understand how we get $\pmb{x}^{T}$ if we differentiate $\frac{\partial ({x}^{T} \pmb{x}) }{\partial \pmb{x}}$.

**What I'm not seeing is how we get** $\frac{\partial (\pmb{x}^{T} x) }{\partial \pmb{x}} = \frac{\partial (\pmb{x}^{T}) }{\partial \pmb{x}}x=\pmb{x}^{T}$

- Why is it that $\pmb{x}$ becomes $\pmb{x}^{T}$ when we differentiate
  $\pmb{x}^{T}$ with respect to $\pmb{x}$ ?

Comment: I see the point : this is not the "product rule" because $x^Tx$ is *not* the "conventional" product of $x^T$ and $x$ but rather the dot product! So the product rule may be written as given but will behave weirdly. My answer below was incorrect, but I did the "product rule proof" approach below and then the second term is actually clear, "essentially" because $x^Ty = y^Tx$ if $x,y$ are column vectors of same length.

Answer (score 3):

As $x^Tx$ is a scalar, $\color{blue}x^Tx=(\color{blue}x^Tx)^T=x^T\color{blue}x.$

Comment: So what are the mechanics of this derivative. Particularly, what is the algebra involved with finding $ \frac{\partial (\pmb{x}^{T}) }{\partial \pmb{x}}x$

Comment: Would you be able to point me to some theorems that may help me with understanding this?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the trace/Frobenius product (denoted by a colon) 
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
As long as the matrices $(A,B)$ have same number of rows/columns, they can have any shape: tall-and-thin, square, short-and-fat. And of course, they can be row or column vectors in which case one recovers the ordinary dot-product
$$a:b = {\rm Tr}(a^Tb) = a\cdot b$$
The properties of the trace allow the terms of a Frobenius product to be rearranged in many ways
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:B &= B:A \\
}$$
For this particular problem, simply take the *differential* of the Frobenius product and then use the commutative property.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= x:x \\
d\phi &= x:dx + dx:x \\&= 2x:dx \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} &= 2x \\
}$$
(Note that this result remains valid when $x$ is a matrix instead of a vector)

Due to a different choice of [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), some authors write this gradient as
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = 2x^T$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}^\top\mathbf{x}$. If write $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0+\epsilon \mathbf{y}$ in the neighborhood of a point $\mathbf{x}_0$ then we may write 
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x})
&=\mathbf{x}^\top\mathbf{x}\\
&=(\mathbf{x}_0+\epsilon \mathbf{y})^\top (\mathbf{x}_0+\epsilon \mathbf{y})\\
&=\mathbf{x}_0^\top \mathbf{x}_0+(2\mathbf{x}^\top)(\epsilon\mathbf{y})+\epsilon^2 \|\mathbf{y}\|^2\\
&=f(\mathbf{x}_0)+(2\mathbf{x}_0^\top) (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)+o(\epsilon^2).
\end{align}
In other words, the function $L(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x}_0)+(2\mathbf{x}_0^\top)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)$ represents the best linear approximation to $f(\mathbf{x})$ in the neighborhood of $\mathbf{x}_0$. As such, we conclude that $\dfrac{df}{d\mathbf{x}}=2\mathbf{x}^\top$.